# Moduli space of vector bundles open in moduli of sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, moduli-space

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety with polarization $\mathcal{O}_X(1)$. For fixed Chern class $r,c_1,c_2....$, do we have an OPEN embedding
$$M^{ss}(X,r,c_1...)_{vec}\subset M^{ss}(X,r,c_1...)$$
of moduli space (Gieseker)-semistable vector bundles into the moduli space of semistable sheaves with the above Chern classes? ( I guess I should assume there is such a vector bundle to start with)

Also, since $\mu$-stable implies stable, is the moduli space of $\mu$-stable vector bundles with the above Chern character openly embedded in $M^{ss}(X,r,c_1...)_{vec}$?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure that the property of being locally free is preserved by S-equivalence, and so that the locus of vector bundles is well-defined for the moduli of semistable sheaves. On a contrary, the locus of STABLE vector bundles is a well-defined open subscheme in the stable locus of the moduli space.